# How to transfer the content of a list to a variable

Tags: python, list, variables, int

How could I transfer the value in the list to the variable while converting it from a string to an int simultaneously?

---

list = ['500']

receive = *This is where the value should appear*

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking of:

```py
your_list = ['500']

receive = int(your_list[0])
print(receive)
```

```
Out[6]: 500
```